# How to determine whether macOS app was started because it needs to handle URL

Tags: macos, url-scheme, launching-application

I have macOS application which registers for custom scheme URL (in Info.plist) and I have a code

`NSAppleEventManager.shared().setEventHandler(self, andSelector: #selector(self.handleGetURL(event:reply:)), forEventClass: UInt32(kInternetEventClass), andEventID: UInt32(kAEGetURL) )`

It all works fine, when my application is launched and somebody clicks on a URL (containing this custom scheme).

However, in the case, if my app isn't started then system start is (which is good). Unfortunately, handleGetURL() isn't called.

There are two problems with it:
- How can I learn whether an application was launched a usual way or was triggered by the system to handle url?
- How can I get a URL which I need to handle (if an application wasn't running)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, registering on applicationDidFinishLaunching is too late. I registered on applicationWillFinishLaunching and everything worked as a charm.